# Object initializer is not accepted in the TFS build server

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild

Object initializer is throwing error in the TFS build server but its running fine in local sandbox.
i'm using VS 2015 in Local Sandox & TFS is using VS 2013.
i think .Net version shouldnt be in issue, both would be using 4.5 & above.

Comment: You gave a clear picture of the environment, but not of your scenario, so there is not enough information to help you. Add to the question some log of the error, when exactly this happens (it is a step in the build, which type of build classic or vNext), what account executes the build and so on.

Comment: What exact error did you get? Are you able to run the build with MSBuild command line on build agent machine?